# where should i focus on to support all 100% mobiles and tablets ignoring whatever their screen sizes or densities?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, screen-size

i want to support all 100% mobiles and tablets and don't want to miss a single device or any android version but to do so

where should i focus either on screen densities or screen size (resolutions)?

i have read many answers here related to supporting different screen size and some were elaborating screen densities but it seems everyone is Right.

one thing i clear till now is to support all densities we should give graphics of all densities in these folders

```
drawable
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

should i use `dimens.xml` in all these values folders all the time in each app to support all devices?

```
values
values-small
values-large
values-xlarge
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
values-w600dp
values-w720dp
values-v11
values-v14
values-v15
values-v16
values-v21
values-sw820dp
values-w820dp
```

should i use `activity_main.xml` and `content_main.xml` Layout files in all these Layout folders all the time in each app to support all devices?

```
layout
layout-small
layout-large
layout-xlarge
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
layout-w600dp
layout-w720dp
layout-v11
layout-v14
layout-v15
layout-v16
layout-v21
layout-sw820dp
layout-w820dp
```

What are the best practices or best approach to just Support all 100% devices?

i searched a lot and found many Supporting multiple screens and multiple densities guides on official android developers website and here on stack overflow and i am still confused like many other beginners in the field of android development and in search of best approach to do so professionally.

```
<supports-screens  android:smallScreens="true"/>
 <supports-screens  android:normalScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

should i just use  element in manifest to support all screens? or it must be used with combination of drawable folders or layout folders?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to add every folder for each density.
Android automatically picks the folder nearest(most similar) to the one that you have defined. So even if you only define values.xml & values-sw600dp.xml, in devices of width 900dp, the values defined in values-ws600dp will be used and in devices of width 500dp, values.xml will be used. (sw stands for smallest width)

Comment: this is not the answer of all my questions..should i use dimens.xml in each value folder and create layout file for each size? as i already trying to handle one of my app's layout i created layout-sw600dp

Comment: layout-sw720dp, layout-sw820dp to handle small screens and tablet large screens and trying to manage button sizes and their margins in relevant dimens.xml files in each folder values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp, values-sw820dp,but still facing issue,buttons are on that place where these should be specially its creating issues on less than4 inch devices and greater than 10 inch tablets and on almost each landscape device..how to handle all of them

Comment: That will depend on your layouts. If you define one layout in sw720dp, then you need to make sure other layouts also look good wrt that in different dimensions. You can start by supporting 2-3 screen size like dimens.xml, dimens-sw600dp and dimens-sw820dp which should cover almost all screen sizes.